# Finding value in rows and columns of a 2D array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to find out if a specified value exists in a given row or a given column of a 2D-array.

The function *existsInRowOrCol* employs the *in* operator, which apparently doesn't work well with nested lists of mixed types.

How can this be solved?

```
import numpy as np

field = np.array([['.','.','.',8,'.','.',3,'.',4],      #0
                 ['.','.',6,'.','.','.','.',7,'.'],     #1
                 [2,'.','.','.',1,'.','.','.','.'],     #2
                 ['.',8,'.',3,'.',4,'.',6,'.'],         #3
                 [1,'.','.','.',5,'.','.',9,'.'],       #4
                 [5,'.','.','.',8,'.',7,'.','.'],       #5
                 ['.',9,'.',1,'.',8,'.',5,'.'],         #6
                 [3,'.','.',6,'.','.',8,'.','.'],       #7
                 ['.','.',8,'.',2,7,'.',1,'.'],         #8
                 ])

def existsInRowOrCol(entry, r, c):
    row = field[r,:]
    print(row)
    if entry in row:
        return True
    col = field[:,c]
    print(col)
    if entry in col:
        return True
    return False

print(existsInRowOrCol(8, 0, 0))
```

The last command prints out false, but it should be true.

**Note:** It works if I replace the dots by zeros.

Answer (score 0):

If you're alright with having your entries in quotes, that worked for me:

```
>>> a = numpy.array(['.','.','8'])
>>> a
array(['.', '.', '8'], 
    dtype='|S1')
>>> row = a[:]
>>> entry = 8
>>> if entry in row:
...    print 'true'
... 
>>> entry = '8'
>>> if entry in row:
...    print 'true'
... 
true
```

Just make sure you pass entry in single quotes.

Comment: so mixing types is a problem?

Comment: It seems to be, for this example anyway.  Perhaps someone has another solution where you can keep it mixed if that is what you need.  I was just trying to provide another alternative to replacing the '.' with 0.

Comment: After a little more playing around... it looks like whenever I mixed '.' and 8 (not in quotes), python would automatically put it in quotes.  That would explain why it wasn't found in your if conditions.  When you print(row) and print(col), do you see single quotes around the numbers?

Comment: Seems like Python casts the type to the next upper type, like here an int to a string. curious...